# VBA download file from FTP url

Tags: vba, download, ftp

Im trying to create VBA code to download a file to specific path from direct FTP link (asynchronously preferred).
I only found code for making it work with http urls, but for FTP i get this error:

"Run-time error '-2146697210 (800c0006)':
The system cannot locate the object specified"

For these first testing have not set username or password for the ftp-server.

My code which is working only for http is below:

```
Sub DownloadFile()

Dim myURL As String
myURL = "ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/test.txt"

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "username", "password"
WinHttpReq.send

myURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody
If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile "C:\FTP\file.txt", 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
    oStream.Close
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I had to go back, but FTP from VBA does involve a bit more - I believe this is the only way without extra controls being installed.  I will post this code below.  http://www.experts-exchange.com/Networking/Protocols/Q_23627204.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to add a module to your project to get the FTP functionality.  Sub FTPdownload has sample code.  Taken from http://experts-exchange.com/Networking/Protocols/Q_23627204.html

```
Private Const FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_UNKNOWN     As Long = 0
Private Const INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD          As Long = &H80000000

Private Declare Function InternetOpenA Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
    ByVal sAgent As String, _
    ByVal lAccessType As Long, _
    ByVal sProxyName As String, _
    ByVal sProxyBypass As String, _
    ByVal lFlags As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function InternetConnectA Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
    ByVal hInternetSession As Long, _
    ByVal sServerName As String, _
    ByVal nServerPort As Long, _
    ByVal sUsername As String, _
    ByVal sPassword As String, _
    ByVal lService As Long, _
    ByVal lFlags As Long, _
    ByVal lcontext As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function FtpGetFileA Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
    ByVal hConnect As Long, _
    ByVal lpszRemoteFile As String, _
    ByVal lpszNewFile As String, _
    ByVal fFailIfExists As Long, _
    ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Long, _
    ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
    ByVal dwContext As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function InternetCloseHandle Lib "wininet" ( _
    ByVal hInet As Long) As Long


Sub FtpDownload(ByVal strRemoteFile As String, ByVal strLocalFile As String, ByVal strHost As String, ByVal lngPort As Long, ByVal strUser As String, ByVal strPass As String)
    'usage
    'FtpDownload "/TEST/test.html", "c:\test.html", "ftp.server.com", 21, "user", "password"
    Dim hOpen   As Long
    Dim hConn   As Long

    hOpen = InternetOpenA("FTPGET", 1, vbNullString, vbNullString, 1)
    hConn = InternetConnectA(hOpen, strHost, lngPort, strUser, strPass, 1, 0, 2)

    If FtpGetFileA(hConn, strRemoteFile, strLocalFile, 1, 0, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_UNKNOWN Or INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0) Then
        Debug.Print "done"
    Else
        Debug.Print "fail"
    End If

    InternetCloseHandle hConn
    InternetCloseHandle hOpen

End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried above way. It is working fine. But If firewall is on or any antivirus firewall is on, above code doesn't works. Please suggest me if anything need to set for skipping the firewall.