# Fetch Excel table from file on FTP server

Tags: excel, ftp, vba

I am storing my Excel files on a FTP server. The file system consits of a central file and several support files. Each support file has one sheet with a table in them. The central file, upon opening it, needs to connect to each support file and fetch its table and copy it in a specific sheet in the central file. The central file will be opened by users with Excel 2016 and Excel 2013 versions.

Excel 2016 gives an option to fetch data in a query from the web, but in Excel 2013 there is no such option.

The question is, how to fetch the data from the support Excel files that are on the FTP server with VBA, so that it works in both Excel 2013 and Excel 2016?

Looking forward to your advice!

Comment: First thought would be to use ftp to get the data.

Comment: The Excel files are stored on a FTP server, yes. But how would you recommend getting in in the central file?

Comment: How do the users open the central file? With Excel, but how in detail?

Comment: The user connects to the server with a client, e.g., WinSCP, and then opens the file with Excel.

Comment: That means the client takes care of opening and later saving the file, right. Either the client has a COM interface and you can use this to retrieve the data from the file on the ftp server or you use the "traditional" way of ftp like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33172900/vba-download-file-from-ftp-url) or maybe you coulde use [Powerquery](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-data-from-external-data-sources-power-query-be4330b3-5356-486c-a168-b68e9e616f5a)

Comment: I don't understand how I can take advantage of the client to fetch data from one Excel file to another. Could you give an example of how it could be done in VBA?

Comment: You need to retrieve data resp. files from the ftp server, so you need to access them. If you want to do it via VBA you need to find a way to open a file via VBA. That means you need to download the file first somehow. So, you could use the client for that if the client offers an interface to VBA which I do not know or you use ftp to do it, see the above link. Or maybe [Powerquery](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-data-from-external-data-sources-power-query-be4330b3-5356-486c-a168-b68e9e616f5a) (which is a free AddIn for 2013 and comes built-in with 2016) can do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I refered to in my comments, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33172900/vba-download-file-from-ftp-url)

```
Private Const FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_UNKNOWN     As Long = 0
Private Const INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD          As Long = &H80000000

Private Declare Function InternetOpenA Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
    ByVal sAgent As String, _
    ByVal lAccessType As Long, _
    ByVal sProxyName As String, _
    ByVal sProxyBypass As String, _
    ByVal lFlags As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function InternetConnectA Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
    ByVal hInternetSession As Long, _
    ByVal sServerName As String, _
    ByVal nServerPort As Long, _
    ByVal sUsername As String, _
    ByVal sPassword As String, _
    ByVal lService As Long, _
    ByVal lFlags As Long, _
    ByVal lcontext As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function FtpGetFileA Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
    ByVal hConnect As Long, _
    ByVal lpszRemoteFile As String, _
    ByVal lpszNewFile As String, _
    ByVal fFailIfExists As Long, _
    ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Long, _
    ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
    ByVal dwContext As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function InternetCloseHandle Lib "wininet" ( _
    ByVal hInet As Long) As Long


Sub FtpDownload(ByVal strRemoteFile As String, ByVal strLocalFile As String, ByVal strHost As String, ByVal lngPort As Long, ByVal strUser As String, ByVal strPass As String)
    'usage
    'FtpDownload "/TEST/test.html", "c:\test.html", "ftp.server.com", 21, "user", "password"
    Dim hOpen   As Long
    Dim hConn   As Long

    hOpen = InternetOpenA("FTPGET", 1, vbNullString, vbNullString, 1)
    hConn = InternetConnectA(hOpen, strHost, lngPort, strUser, strPass, 1, 0, 2)

    If FtpGetFileA(hConn, strRemoteFile, strLocalFile, 1, 0, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_UNKNOWN Or INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0) Then
        Debug.Print "done"
    Else
        Debug.Print "fail"
    End If

    InternetCloseHandle hConn
    InternetCloseHandle hOpen

End Sub
```

With that code you could download the support files and then open them with Excel in order to update the central file.

The other option might be [**PowerQuery**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-data-from-external-data-sources-power-query-be4330b3-5356-486c-a168-b68e9e616f5a) (free AddIn for Excel 2013 and built-in with Excel 2016)

Comment: Thank you, Storax! I will look into it next week. Keep in touch!

Comment: During these days the server was changed and also the way I can access the files. So I will not be able to test the code. Thank you anyways for helping!